# error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I get the code in ruby and java and existing stackoverflow questions cannot fix my problem, it's not DISPLAY question, here is my code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "${System.env.HOME}/Downloads/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
    Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
    searchBox.submit();
    Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
    driver.quit();
```

I get following error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320) on port 12068
Only local connections are allowed.
Jan 02, 2017 12:26:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Jan 02, 2017 12:27:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 26 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'roroco', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-21-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 4678ee095cbba894a70c107c28c1bb44
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$get.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at TestChromeDriver.main(TestChromeDriver.groovy:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to mention .exe extension of chrome driver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "${System.env.HOME}/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: It's linux chromedriver